# List the paths of a directory in an array in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am a beginner in Qt creator, so my question is how to load the path of a directory into an array, for example :

[image: here are some directory]

If I want to load all the video paths in an array by order, how can I make it? I want an array called `video[ ]`, then `video[0]` is the `video2017-05-03-13:54:41B` in the image, then `video[1]` is `video2017-05-03-14:01:58B` etc. And then show the paths in a label or a listWidget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QDir recoredDir(path);
QStringList dirs = recoredDir.entryList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot
                                                   | QDir::Dirs);
```

This will get you all the directories in path to the list 'dirs'

Comment: Notice that the ordering is not guaranteed - if you want some particular order you gave to sort them yourself.